# Polymer custom element not obeying parent html element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

I am using Polymer 1.0 - My page is contained within a `paper-scroll-header-panel` and I am trying to turn part of the main toolbar into a custom element (`my-header`):

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel condenses keep-condensed-header>

    <!-- Main Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar class="tall layout horizontal" id="title-toolbar">
            <my-header id="myHeaderElement"></my-header>
    </paper-toolbar>
```

`my-header` custom element looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-header">
<style>

</style>
<template>
    <div class="bottom center horizontal layout" id="testing">
        <paper-button>Title</paper-button>
        <div class="flex"></div>
        <paper-button on-click="openLang">lang</paper-button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-header",
        behaviors: [
            Polymer.IronFitBehavior,
            Polymer.IronResizableBehavior
        ],
        ready: function() {
            this.fit();
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem is that layout attributes `bottom center horizontal layout` aren't being applied properly since its not obeying the parent `<paper-toolbar>` element.
It renders like this:
[image: layout issue]

but the it should render with the text on the bottom of the orange box and the `Title` on the left, long flex box in the middle, and `LANG` on the far right. If I pull the HTML out of the custom element and stick it directly into the index.html file it works just fine.

As you can see I added some behaviors to the element and have played around with calling them in the `ready` function but to no avail..

I also tried pulling the whole `<paper-toolbar>` element into the custom element but that just created even more problems with `<paper-scroll-header-panel>`'s functionality.

How can I get this custom element to stay inside its parent and obey the formatting classes/attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying class `bottom` on your element in light dom.

```
<paper-toolbar class="tall layout horizontal" id="title-toolbar">
        <my-header class="bottom" id="myHeaderElement"></my-header>
</paper-toolbar>
```

Comment: I honestly can't believe that I didn't think of that...so simple and it worked. I must have spent too much time staring at this thing. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'll also add that I put all the classes from the div inside the custom element onto the DOM object and then ended up deleting the extra wrapper div in the custom element.

Comment: Good idea, I write far less divs with custom elements. :)